# How do you add text in a .data()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: $('.item').data('query_selector'),
    dataType: "html"
```

(It works fine, and it calls back something like `"item=Mann+Co.+Supply+Crate&quality=6&tradable=1&craftable=1&numeric=crate&comparison=eq&value=47&australium=-1"`)

Now, in order to be valid, it needs to be `"/classifieds?(query_selector)"`(So in the case above, `"/classidieds?item=Mann+Co.+Supply+Crate&quality=6&tradable=1&craftable=1&numeric=crate&comparison=eq&value=47&australium=-1"`)
How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put the url string out of ajax

```
var requestString = '/classifieds?' + $('.item').data('query_selector');

$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: requestString,
  dataType: "html"
});
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you <3